# duas patterns diferentes no mesmo input HTML

Tags: html, input

Olá, Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de colocar mais de uma pattern como alternativa à primeira no html

por exemplo, uma pessoa só pode usar Gmail.com e Hotmail.com, para que ela preencha com uma **OU** outra

ex:

```
<input type='text' pattern='[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@gmail.com'>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é possível adicionar mais de um regex no atributo pattern, o que pode ser feito é adicionar um grupo contendo o que você quer.

```
<input type='text' pattern='[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@(gmail|hotmail).com'>
```